# How do I create a System DSN

Tags: odbc, mondrian

I need to create a System DSN called MondrianFoodMart that points to /MondrianFoodMart.mdb file. The instructions to do this are very
confusing.

More specifically I am trying to do section 2.1 of this confusing website:
http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/installation.php

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Comment: [This section?](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/installation.php#2_1_Microsoft_Access)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the "ODBC Data Source Administrator" dialog by navigating Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)
2. Select the "System DSN" tab and pass Add
3. Select the Microsoft Access Driver and press Finish
4. Enter the Data Source Name "MondrianFoodMart" (and a suitable description)
5. Press "Select" and use the "Select Database" dialog to pick the .mdb
6. Press Ok, keep your fingers crossed and test

Comment: I'll give that a shot tomorrow. Today, I'm away from the computer to do so.

Comment: any way to do it non-GUI from an installer?

Answer (score 0):

While in docs they say about JDBC URL to Access db: `jdbc:odbc:MondrianFoodMart` it may be easier to use such URL in other form:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=MONDRIAN_HOME\\demo\\access\\MondrianFoodMart.mdb
```

Of course replace MONDRIAN_HOME with real directory name. It may be useful if such URL is part of configuration file. Then creating DNS will not be necessary.